# Runtime Error webpackJsonp is not defined Stack ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[W][webpackJsonp]

Unlikely returned an reference error "WebpackJsonp not defined" in error popup.

I found one of Stackoverflow answered to put your vendor.js before main.js but unfortunately it's not work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking Changes

This means that src/index.html must be modified to include a new vendor script tag . This new script tag must be placed above the main.js script tag. For exampl

```
<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- all code from node_modules directory is here -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
```